# Jquery Exporting HTML5 table to Excel in IE without ActiveX object?

Tags: jquery, excel, html, export, html-table

I am trying to export HTML table's contents to an Excel in IE using jquery. I realize that they are many threads that discuss this. But all of them specify either this code:

```
var ExcelApp = new ActiveXObject("Excel.Application");
var ExcelSheet = new ActiveXObject("Excel.Sheet");
ExcelSheet.Application.Visible = true;
```

or this:

```
  window.open('data:application/vnd.ms-excel,' + encodeURIComponent($('#dataTable').html()));
```

The first one works in IE, but I would prefer not to use ActiveX object as it goes against the default security settings of my IE. The second one doesn't work in IE. I want to do this client side using jQuery or JS.

Answer (score 1):

Let's assume your html table has an id="exportTable"

you can export the table to an xls file using:

```
window.open('data:application/vnd.ms-excel,' + $('#exportTable').html());
```

you're trying to either open an application or write to the file system from within your browser. That means that if the default security settings won't allow that, there's really no way around that except either change the security settings (I assume that's not an option) or try this in e.g. Chrome (maybe not an option either) because this is working fine for me.

Writing to the File System from the browser isn't something that's allowed by default and, as you can imagine, with good reason.

One alternative might be to investigate the possibility to create a new Google Docs Spreadsheet using your table data.
I found an [interesting article](http://gdatatips.blogspot.be/2009/07/create-new-google-docs-spreadsheet-from.html) describing how you could approach this, but I haven't any experience with this.

Comment: I am trying to understand the article you've pointed me to. Could you please help me by elaborating? The data in my HTML table is not in Base64 format and needs to be converted before I place it in an excel? How do I do that assuming I've converted it to Base64?

Comment: That does not work in IE. I've already tried that. I hadn't mentioned it properly. Edited my question now.

Comment: I don't need to open the excel as such, provided the user a save as / download dialog box will be the best. Any pointers on how I can do that? Thanks for trying to help.